# Eclipse Mars freezes on Subclipse Password store

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu-12.04, subclipse, eclipse-mars

I've got a current Eclipse Mars installation on an Ubuntu 12.04 here which seems to work fine, but unfortunately, whenever I choose to store the password for the svn repository, Eclipse freezes. If I don't check the "Store Password" checkbox, everything works fine (besides the password not being saved, obviously).

Anyone got an idea what the problem could be? User is owner of the workspace and eclipse directories, of course.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is because of a missing library that was removed with Luna and Mars release. Find org.eclipse.core.runtime.compatibility.auth_3.2.300.v20120523-2004.jar and put it in Eclipse/plugins and it will work just fine

Comment: Thanks but it cause a crash on Eclipse Oxygen 3 (Mars 2018)